# Numeric string in JavaScript esb

Tags: javascript, foreach, iterator, wso2, payload

Why on the first log I see the value while when I pass it to the property wso2 I see nothing?

```
 log.info("LOG_JS");                 
             log.info(uuid)      
             mc.setProperty("UUID_current", uuid);</script>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="get-property('UUID_current')" name="UUID_current"/>
        </log>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript mediator you should log in this way:

```
var x = body.data.link;
var log = mc.getServiceLog();
log.info("your log name:" + x);
```

In your log, you will see

```
your log name: http://google.com/
```